# Disable built-in spell checking on Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android

So this is a fairly odd problem:  I am currently working on an app using the latest SDK/ADT with my android:minSdkVersion set to 8.

When the app is deployed onto an ICS device (Galaxy Nexus), android is adding red-squiggly underlines to words it thinks are miss-spelled in TextView widgets.

See screenshot:
[image: Galaxy Nexus TextView with spellcheck]

The layout in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="This is a test of a TextView showing the spell checking when it shouldn&apos;t.  Phunware.com loves the game Baldr Force. Funimation.com"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried adding android:editable="false" to the widgets, with no effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like if you have the android:inputType specified, this enabled spell check on a widget.  Oops!

Comment: Is there a way to disable it with using android:inputType?

Answer (score 13):

The way to disable it is to set inputType to "textNoSuggestions"